# How to find Chatter Image on Salesforce

Tags: chatter, images

How can I check the size of the `Chatter` image uploaded for a User with a Custom Profile?

I'm unable to even find these Users in Chatter tab.

I've already run a query on User object with `SmallPhotoUrl` and `FullPhotoUrl` but that only gives the link. I need to check the image and its size on Salesforce environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to see all Files and Data related to a User. If you know the name of the user you can just go to:

1. **Setup** (right top corner)
2. **Manage Users** under **Administer**
3. **Users**
4. Select the user by clicking on his/her name
5. On the column from the right scroll until you find **Used Data Space**
6. Click on "**View**"
7. You can do the same for **Used File Space**

In both cases, you should be able to see files, photos, documents, and the rest of files this user has under his name.

Any **Chatter** fields should be there as well.